# Issues dealing with null when duck typing unknown object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function in my app which duck types an input object:

```
export const isMyType = (arg: unknown): arg is MyType => {
  return (
    arg != null && 
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'prop1' in arg &&
    'prop2' in arg &&
    'prop3' in arg
  );
};
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJaoLIE8AquYwcAvHABQCGUA5gFxwCuyA1shAO7ICUZAfHADeAKDhwowGEyjJKY8XBq04AQnLImAGy1wAZHrgLxMIsAgAzJXTKlyAcggAjAFbAEMe-r3G49sFAQYACMXhhyyt6%20-oFgAExhETYG0QFBAMyJ1rQKPADcIgC%20eUA) is a Typescript playground reproduction.

I was previously using Typescript 3.9.7 and this function worked fine.  I upgraded to Typescript 4.0.5 recently and line 5 shows a compilation error: *Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)*.  My expectation is that `null` is dealt with on line 3, but apparently not.  I've also tried adding the following to start my function, but to no avail:

```
if (arg == null) {
  return false;
}
```

My app errors on `no-non-null-assertions` so I can't simply add `!` after `arg` to correct with this.

**How can I deal with this `null` error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the conditional uses the last type check and `typeof arg === 'object'` asserts it's a nullable object.  I made the following change which it likes:

```
export const isMyType = (arg: unknown): arg is MyType => {
  return (
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    arg != null && 
    'prop1' in arg &&
    'prop2' in arg &&
    'prop3' in arg
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

```
// I usually have this typeguard laying around
const isObject = (arg:unknown) : arg is object => typeof arg === "object" && arg !== null;

const isMyType = (arg: unknown): arg is MyType => {
  return isObject(arg) &&
    'prop1' in arg &&
    'prop2' in arg &&
    'prop3' in arg
};
```